# Selenium WebDriver Switch Browser Offline C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am trying to switch my browser to offline in middle of the tests. In Network tab I can do it manually as shown in picture below.

[image: Picture]

I have tried this and did not work because ChromeNetworkConditions seems to be non  existent.

```
var driver = new ChromeDriver(); 

driver.NetworkConditions = new ChromeNetworkConditions()
{
    IsOffline = true, 
    DownloadThroughput = 5000, 
    UploadThroughput = 5000, 
    Latency = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5) 
};
```

I can not get this code to work on my `.NET6.0 Selenium 4.3.0`

Does `ChromeNetworkConditions()` still exist? If yes, what is the library I should import?

Anyone has any idea how to switch to offline with Selenium  WebDriver on `.net 4.3.0` ?

Comment: _shown in picture below_: Where is the picture?

Comment: Picture hyperlink